# How do I get Vertex AI pipelines to see cloudshell files?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am running a vertex AI pipeline, from Cloudshell:

```
  if __name__ == '__main__':
    sfile= open("/path/to/keyfile.json", "r")
    compile()
    trigger_pipeline()
```

I have declared `sfile` here because by the time I get to the component, the file system no longer sees the file (God knows why):

```
@component(
     packages_to_install=['google-cloud-secret-manager']
 )
def print_secret_op(project_id: str, secret_id: str, version_id: str) -> str:    
    from google.cloud import secretmanager
    from google.oauth2 import service_account
    
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(sfile)
```

but here `sfile` doesn't have a value and I don't know how to pass it in (I can pass the file path but for some reason the home folder is empty at this stage). How can I pass the file into this, or why can the file no longer be seen at this point? (I tried declaring `sfile` at the start of the python program but the component still couldn't see it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot use the cloudshell as a regular filesystem for datastorage, you need to store your file in a cloud storage bucket and access it with the [cloud storage api](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python)

here is the python refference documentation: https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html

Comment: Thanks. Wish I had know that 2 days ago!!

Comment: no probem, hope it helps